Why does this API call work in a Pages but not App Based Router Next.js app
In have a Next.js app using App Router with the following structure:
.
└── src /
    └── app/
        └── api/
            └── hello.js

Where hello.js is simply:
export default function handler(req, res) {
    res.status(200).json({ text: 'Hello' });
  }

When I run this app using npm run dev and visit http://localhost:3000/api/hello I get a 404 error.
In contrast, I also have a Next.js app using Pages Router with the following structure:
.
└── pages/
    └── api/
        └── hello.js

When I visit this app at http://localhost:3001/api/hello, I get a response of {"text":"Hello"}.
How can I modify my first app to also give a response?

Writing Router Handlers in the App Router is different from writing APIs in the Pages Router.

File structure:

The pages has file-based routing, the file pages/api/hello.ts is accessible through /api/hello. But the App Router has folder-based routing. To make a route handler create a file called route.{ts,tsx,js,jsx,...} in a folder app/api/hello/route.ts (accessable through /api/hello).

Exports

In the Pages Router you could export a default export (e.g. export default handler) that handles all HTTP methods.
In the App Router, there is no default export. instead there are named exports by the name of the method in UPPER_CASE
export async function GET() {}
export async function POST() {}
export async function PUT() {}
export async function PATCH() {}
export async function DELETE() {}
export async function HEAD() {}
export async function OPTIONS() {}


function params:

in the Pages directory the handler accepts these params handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse).
in the App Router, every method function accepts (req: NextRequest, event: { params }).

Note: the type of the request is NextRequest (imported from "next/server") not NextApiRequest (imported from "next").


Sending a response

Sending a response in the Pages Router is similar to the code snippet in the question:
export default function handler(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json({ text: 'Hello' });
}

In the App Router, to send a response, you can return a Response or NextResponse.
import { type NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(req: NextRequest) {
  const body = await req.json();
  const { searchParams } = req.nextUrl;

  return NextResponse.json({ message: "Hello World" }, { status: 200 })
  
  // or

  return Response.json({ message: "Hello World" }, { status: 200 })
}


For further reading: Docs
